# How to sell a ring to someone in another country?

Tags: international-transfer, selling

I want to sell a ring worth more than 10 000 euros. There is a one guy in France who is interested. I told him I am not in France yet, but will be there probably the next month. He said he is about to make a proposal to his girlfriend, so he wants it in the next few days.

I would accept to come, but I want to be sure he wouldn't cancel it.
How to tell him to pay in advance at least for the urgent travel into his country ?

The route would cost for about 400-500eu.

Comment: tell him to pay for your flight :)

Comment: Have you considered using an escrow service (of YOUR choice)?

Comment: Why not have him come to you? Or at the least have him just pay for your ticket? Perhaps if he buys the ring then you'll discount the purchase by the ticket cost... that way everyone wins.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - never heard about it. Isn't it similiar to paypal's payment process ?

Comment: @mlathe - I bet he wouldn't even think to come to buy something like that in foreign country. I told him today, if he want, I can come tomorrow but he should deposit at least 400eu to my paypal account. Waiting for his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask for a down payment of 1000 Euros through paypal or a similar payment source.  If he backs out, he forfeits the 1000 eu.  If that happens your airfare is covered plus some spending money.

If he does not cancel then the down counts towards payment.

In order for him to feel safer, I would take a pic of the ring with today's paper, or something that can be dated as recent.

Keep in mind you guys can meet at a bank to do the exchange.  This way you both feel safer.

The bottom line is what are you willing to do to sell the ring at that price?

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was thinking about paypal too. What concerns about Banks - never thought that's possible, I will search more about it.

Comment: Would the seller really be protected? Couldn't the PayPal payment be disputed and reversed by the buyer?

Comment: I'am wondering also, if I will be protected ? ie.: couple hours after our meeting, can he safely be refunded without my approval throught paypal?